# Inconsistent callback while using crossroads.js

Tags: javascript, callback

While using below route in crossroads

```
crossroads.addRoute('#test1', function(){console.log("test1 callback");} )
crossroads.addRoute('#test2', function(){console.log("test2 callback");} )
```

And testing using JavaScript console herewith the output

```
crossroads.parse("#test1")
test1 callback hp-controller.js:66

crossroads.parse("#test1")

crossroads.parse("#test2")
test2 callback hp-controller.js:67

crossroads.parse("#test2")

crossroads.parse("#test1")
test1 callback hp-controller.js:66

crossroads.parse("#test1")
```

I am confused why sometimes callback is happening but some other time are not. It seems repeating callback in a row is prevented?

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to your current location, you don't get the event that you changed locations.